# Save in DB from Listview Django with a form in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

im building a little survey app, I need to show each answer with their corresponding answers in one page, so im doing it with ListView and paginate by 1.

```
class TriviaView(ListView):
    model = Preguntas
    paginate_by = 1
    template_name = 'trivias.html'
```

Obviously each answer has to be save it in database, but here is where i get lose, i dont know how to save in DB each answer the user reply.

Template:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
    <p>{% for pregunta in object_list %} {{pregunta.pregunta}}</p>
    {% for respuesta in pregunta.respuestas_set.all %} 
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}"><button type="button">{{respuesta.respuesta}}</button> </a>
    {% endif %}             
    {% endfor %}            
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Models:

```
class Trivia(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categorias)
    contador = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "Trivias" 

class Preguntas(models.Model):
    trivia = models.ForeignKey(Trivia)
    pregunta = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pregunta

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "Preguntas"

class Respuestas(models.Model):
    pregunta = models.ForeignKey(Preguntas)
    respuesta = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.respuesta

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "Respuestas"

class Records(models.Model):
    trivia = models.ForeignKey(Trivia)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pregunta = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    respuesta = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

How can i save in Records model each answer the user pick with their corresponding answer?.

Sorry for the spanish attributes, the client ask it like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should have to use form-wizard for this kind of work here is link how form-wizard works :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the Related Objects syntax.

Usage would be:

```
# get one question
p = Preguntas.objects.get(pk=1)

# get all responses
p.respuestas_set.all()
```

The *Django Docs* are here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Comment: thanks, but how can i get the option of the user has pick in the template? Thats you said goes in get_queryset in the TriviaView?

Comment: @dfrojas you can send the Users choice in the template as a URL argument, and then process it. Like a Django `forms.py` form.